# adding 2 large integers using arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is my task: Write a program that inputs two positive integers of, at most, 20 digits and outputs the sum of the numbers. If the sum of the numbers has more than 20 digits, output the sum with an appropriate message. Your program must, at least, contain a function to read and store a number into an array and another function to output the sum of the numbers. (Hint: Read numbers as strings and store the digits of the number in the reverse order.)

Ive pretty much gotten things fixed, its just that my output is printing each index's sum rather than a whole number with multiple digits. Also, I tried to add code to deter the user from typing over 20 characters but I get an error regarding the string variable not being able to used in this statement: if (user_str1>20)

```
    int read_strings(int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
    string user_str1;
    string user_str2;

    cout << "enter a positive integer of, at most, 20 digits " << endl;
    cin >> user_str1;

    for (int ind2 = user_str1.length() - 1; ind2 >= 0; ind2--)
    {
        arr1[ind2] = static_cast<int>(user_str1[ind2]) - static_cast<int>    ('0');
    }

    cout << "now enter a second number with the same conditions as the first      " << endl;
    cin >> user_str2;


    for (int d = user_str2.length() - 1; d >= 0; d--)
    {
        arr2[d] = static_cast<int>(user_str2[d]) - static_cast<int>('0');
    }
    return user_str1.length();
}
void print_sum(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size)
{
    string user_str1;
    string user_str2;

    int sum_arr[20];


    int carry = 0;
    for (int e = 0; e < size; e++)
    {
        if (arr1[e] + arr2[e] + carry > 9)
        {
            sum_arr[e] = arr1[e] + arr2[e] + carry;
            sum_arr[e] = sum_arr[e] % 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sum_arr[e] = arr1[e] + arr2[e] + carry;
            carry = 0;
        }
        cout << "the sum of the two arrays is: " << sum_arr[e];
        cout << endl;
    }


}
int main(){

    int arr1[20];
    int arr2[20];
    int size = read_strings(arr1, arr2);
    print_sum(arr1, arr2, size);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code review?

Comment: “In C++, the largest `int` value is 2147483647” is **incorrect in two main ways**. First because there's no such limit imposed by the C++ standard (instead it imposes a lower limit, via the C standard, that the value representation of `int` must be at least 16 bits). Secondly the value representation of `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: Note that 20 decimal digits is roughly 20/3 ~= 7 groups of 3 digits. Each group of 3 digits requires about 10 binary digits. So we're talking about roughly 70 binary digits, which is more than the common 64-bit `long long int` can handle directly. Still you can use `long long int` to check your results for not-quite-as-large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

[c4018](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2.aspx) is a warning telling you that you are comparing a signed number against an unsigned number. `e` is a signed integer, std::string::length returns an unsigned number (what sense does a negative string length make?). Change the type of `e` to an unsigned number.

As for passing parameters as references you'll probably want something like this:

```
void read_strings(string &user_string1, string &user_string2);
void print_sum(string &user_string1, string &user_string2);
// replace same-named local variables with the parameters
```

...

```
int main() {
  string user_string1, user_string2;
  read_strings(user_string1, user_string2);
  print_sum(user_string1, user_string2);
  // ...
 }
```

Comment: Re "Change the type of e to an unsigned number" gets rid of the warning while keeping the issue warned about. A better approach is to use signed integer for numerical values (it's better because it gets rid of the underlying issue and not just the symptom, namely, no more chance of unintended wrapping implicit conversion). Use unsigned ones for bitlevel stuff.

Comment: How do I change e to an unsigned number? I havent learned that yet. Also, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> **”** I dont know why im getting warning c4018 on line 63: `for (int e = 0; e < user_str1.length(); e++)`

… that's because your're comparing a *signed* integer with an *unsigned* integer of same or greater size, and with the current C++ rules – reportedly unlike the original rules – the signed integer is then first converted up to the unsigned type. And if it's negative, then this can produce a really large number. For example, the following is guaranteed to always produce `true`:

```
string( "Blah" ).length() < -3
```

Pretty counter-intuitive, yes? That's why the compiler warns.

A simple fix is to convert the unsigned integer to a signed one, either with a cast here or by defining general size and length functions. Here's a cast:

```
for ( int e = 0; e < int( user_str1.length() ); e++ )
```

Note 1: it's generally best to avoid casts, because they tell the compiler that you know what you're doing, and often the “need” for a cast is perceived precisely because one doesn't really know, and then the compiler, working on a wrong assumption that it's OK, may do Unholy Things.

Note 2: this syntax should not be used for casts of pointers or references, because there it can be translated to different kinds of casts depending on the particular types involved, which can change through maintenance. For pointer or reference casts use the named C++ casts.

---

Re

> **”** Also, how do I make reference parameters for both functions, pass them and calling these functions to the main fxn

… note first that it isn't so good an idea. When a function returns some information, just let it return that information. Don't think about optimizing (avoid copying) by using a reference parameter, at least until **measurements** have shown that the return of a value is a critical bottleneck. Doing it before that is called **premature optimization**. And the great computer scientist Donald Knuth remarked once that [premature optimization is the root of all Evil™](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Your task as a programmer is not primarily to communicate to a compiler what machine code to generate. Your task is to express the effect that you want, in a way so that the code will be easy to understand and modify for others (or yourself!) at a later time, i.e., communicating to humans, not to a compiler.

That said, the function `read_strings` is evidently asking the user for two strings of ASCII digits, and communicating them back to the calling code in the form of two arrays of digit values. That's best done by returning the digit value arrays as a function result. There are two issues with this:

- Raw arrays can't be returned directly as function results, so you need some wrapper, either using e.g. `std::vector` directly, or defining a class, e.g. called `Large_int`.
- The function name `read_strings` becomes misleading when the result is a pair of `Large_int` values.

A reasonable definition of `Large_int` for your purposes, is

```
class Large_int
{
private:
    vector<int> digits_;

public:
    auto n_digits() const -> int { return digits_.size(); }

    auto digit( int const i ) const -> int { return digits_[i]; }

    auto to_string() const
        -> string
    {
        // TODO:
    }

    void operator+=( Large_int const& other )
    {
        // TODO:
    }

    friend
    auto operator+( Large_int const& a, Large_int const& b )
        -> Large_int
    {
        Large_int result = a;
        result += b;
        return result;
    }

    Large_int() {}

    Large_int( string const& digits )
    {
        // TODO:
        // Throws exception if `digits` is an invalid spec.
    }
};
```

So instead of

```
void read_strings()
```

… you can technically use reference arguments like this:

```
void read_from_user( Large_int& a, Large_int& b )
```

…, but better just return the pair:

```
auto ints_from_user() -> pair<Large_int, Large_int>
```

… where `pair` is `std::pair` from the `<utility>` header, and where the function naming, describing its result, reflects the new signature.

In your `main` function you can then do e.g.

```
pair<Large_int, Large_int> const numbers = ints_from_user();
cout << "The first number is " << numbers.first.to_string() << endl;
```

---

Now, in the `read_strings` code there are two identical attempts at converting a typed in specification to an array of digit values. You should better *define a function* for that. That will not only simplify `read_strings`, but will also avoid the current problems with repeated code. Repeated code is often repeated bugs. About 80% of all programming work is maintenance, and when a maintenance programmer has to find and visit all instances of chunk of code, perhaps with small variations here and there, then not only does that take time and money, but it's likely to result in some new bugs introduced, and some existing bugs overlooked.

This is called **separation of concerns**: to let each function do only one thing, and do that thing well. It simplifies things.

In the above I have assumed that the converting function is a constructor of a class `Large_int`. This reflects its single purpose: to convert a specification to a value of a type.

Comment: So what do you suggest I name my function? And my task tells me to make one function for reading and storing the number into an array and another for outputting the sum...isn't that what I've done? Just looking for some help.

Comment: @KennedyD.: Re last issue first, yes, you've done exactly what the assignment calls for. But it can be done in many different ways. Separating concerns is a standard technique that helps. When you have a separate convert-to-digits-vector function you can *use* that inside the function that reads-and-converts, if you want to structure things that way. That avoids the repeated code. Avoiding repeated code is called the **DRY** principle, *Don't Repeat Yourself*. :)

Comment: Still re the last issue, I think now the advice I gave is somewhat flawed. It does make sense to read and convert, because it can be viewed as reading values of a new type. So, the separation of concerns advice is good, but what I wrote about just returning strings, to single that out on its own, I now think is flawed. It's the conversion to digits, or more generally to *a value of an “arbitrary size integer” type*, that's important to factor out as a function, to avoid repeating that code. I'm sorry.

Comment: Re naming, that's very much a personal preference thing. Generally accepted advice: name the functions so that you make *the calling code* understandable and clear, ideally that the calling code reads like ordinary English. But this ideal can create far too long and verbose names, and also there are strong conventions like `i` for a loop index, so one must apply common sense. I prefer to name functions by the results they produce, e.g. `digits_from`( a string ). But e.g. Marshall Cline, author of the C++ FAQ, prefers verbs, like `to_digits`( a string ).

Comment: I edited the answer extensively to address your questions and to reflect my new view of the advice I gave. Happily there was only one existing upvote, so, not much upvoting invalidated. :)

Comment: thanks for the help, but your advice is too advanced for the level of c++ I am at in my course.

Comment: You can replace the class with a set of functions operating directly on `std::vector`, or on a `struct` containing one. That said, I taught C++ at a college here in Norway in the mid 1990s, and have helped a lot of students since then. And I am sure that defining your own classes is *not* a too advanced topic. After all, students starting with an "easier" language such as Java have no choice but to define classes, since these languages don't offer free-standing functions. ;-)

Comment: Im saying that I shouldnt use topics not taught to me yet by my professor. However, again thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Define two arrays of integers of size 20 in the `main()`. Let's say `int num1[20]` and `int num2[20]`
- Declare your reading and print functions as `void func(int* p1, int* p2)` and call them `func(num1, num2)`
- You do not need auxiliary array when reading numbers. Do

  `arr1[a] = user_str1[ind1] - static_cast<int>('0');`
- Check the length of the input string **before** converting it into numbers and print a relevant error message if the number is too long
- You need more declarative info. For example, you definitely should add `#include <string>` and declare strings as `std::string`. Your warnings may be result of those undeclared strings

Answer (score 0):

The arrays `arr1[] and arr2[]` you declare in the two function are different (even if they have the same name) with scope local to the function they are declared,so are the strings `user_str1 and user_str2`, but you are treating them as they are the same which will give you incorrect results. One way of doing this is to declare the arrays in your main function and pass it along to your other functions and you also need to change your function prototypes like this(assuming the number of digit in both numbers are equal):

```
void print_sum(int arr1[],int arr2[],int size);//takes two arrays of the same number of elements
int read_strings(int arr1[],int arr2[]);//takes two arrays,read the strings inside ,store then in the arrays and return the resulting number of elements in the arrays
```

And remove the `int arr1[20]` and `int arr2[20]` declarations from both of your functions. Remove the loops in your `read_strings()` function that contains `arr1[a] = user_str1[ind1];a++;` and `arr2[c] = user_str2[ind3];c++;` since they don't do anything useful.

Change this in your `read_strings()` function:

```
int b=0;
for (int ind2 = user_str1.length() - 1; ind2 >= 0; ind2--)
{
    arr1[b] = static_cast<int>(user_str1[b]) - static_cast<int>('0');

}
```

To

```
for (int ind2 = user_str1.length() - 1; ind2 >= 0; ind2--)
{
    arr1[ind2] = static_cast<int>(user_str1[ind2 ]) - static_cast<int>('0');    
}
```

Return the size of one of your strings from the `read_strings()` function as `return user_str1.length();`

Change you loop in `print_sum()` function from  `for (int e = 0; e < user_str1.length(); e++)` to `for (int e = 0; e < size; e++)`, `size` is passed as an argument to the function.

Then you can call these function from main:

```
//main function
int arr1[20];
int arr2[20];
int size=read_strings(arr1,arr2);
print_sum(arr1,arr2,size);
```

Comment: my output adds each index with this change of code, i need to manipulate both strings and get one whole number. also how would i implement something to stop the string from being more than 20 characters?